# Как получить запись колонки, которая соответствует каждой из указанных записей другой колонки?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть таблица хранящая отношения многие ко многим.

```
UserId                                  RoomId  DateAdd                     id
2e8ba91e-c091-437a-8823-43c403d52d87    2066    21.08.2017 20:11:15.257     5
2e8ba91e-c091-437a-8823-43c403d52d87    2067    21.08.2017 20:11:40.477     7
5c8de7b8-abb0-417c-971e-b2217d6a3652    2066    21.08.2017 20:11:23.197     6
cacb2d37-0d73-4848-8758-b5af8841b13d    2067    21.08.2017 20:11:43.260     8
```

Как наилучшим образом получить (или не получить) id комнаты, которому соответствуют все из переданных Id юзеров?

У меня есть решение, но мне кажется что оно не оптимально.

```
SELECT
  c.RoomId
FROM (SELECT
    UserRooms.RoomId
   ,COUNT(*) AS RoomCount
  FROM dbo.UserRooms
  WHERE UserRooms.UserId IN ('2e8ba91e-c091-437a-8823-43c403d52d87', '5c8de7b8-abb0-417c-971e-b2217d6a3652')
  GROUP BY UserRooms.RoomId) c
WHERE c.RoomCount = 2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> мне кажется что оно не оптимально

Если всегда передаётся строго два GUID - то да, можно и лучше:

```
SELECT t1.RoomID
FROM dbo.UserRooms t1, dbo.UserRooms t2
WHERE t1.RoomId = t2.RoomId
  AND t1.UserId = '2e8ba91e-c091-437a-8823-43c403d52d87'
  AND t2.UserId = '5c8de7b8-abb0-417c-971e-b2217d6a3652'
```

Но если количество передаваемых GUID не установлено, то вполне себе запрос - ну разве что обёртка тут лишняя:

```
SELECT RoomId
FROM dbo.UserRooms
WHERE UserId IN ('2e8ba91e-c091-437a-8823-43c403d52d87'
                ,'5c8de7b8-abb0-417c-971e-b2217d6a3652')
GROUP BY RoomId
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
```

Comment: Да в перспективе конечно же лучше по списку, Спасибо!